# What do you use for collaboration and code review?

Tags: version-control, project-management, configuration-management

What project management solution can you use for grouping together related commits? Lets say you have a few hunderd modules and you need to make changes which affect 5 or 10 of these. Is there a solution that lets you open a ticket and track your subversion commits while keeping a group of people in the loop?

Comment: Use Git and tag the commits.

Comment: More thinking of a collaboration platform. A place where changes can be discussed too.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on the size of your team.

A small team can settle for just using GIT/SVN (or any CVS really) and make sure that everyone pulls/fetches from the integration branch frequently as a habit. If needed, use email to inform everyone about code changes or do scheduled commits to integration branch. This way, instead of letting people know that you did a commit, you can tell people when to expect a commit.

If we are talking about a big team/s, Project Management tools like JIRA should have the flexibility to send an email to a watchlist once a task is done (effectively, a code was pushed) and provide other information about the finished task (such as Affected versions/modules)

Actually, there are different ways to answer your questions depending on the need and workflow of the team but hopefully I've provided some ideas for you here.